# How do you prevent more than two decimal places in datagridview column in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've looked it up and I've tried everything but nothing is working. My 'Price' column which gets its data from an sql server has the values comes up as "4.9900" or "3.5000". There's always a 00 at the end, and I've tried even not putting any defaultCellstyle formats in but it's still #.##00. Any suggestions?

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
//doesn't work

dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00";
//doesn't work

dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);
//doesn't work
```

Comment: *You may use the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView and insert this line of code in this event handler*: if (e.ColumnIndex==1) e.Value = String.Format(""0.00", e.Value)

Comment: @Graffito tried and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @GrantWinney yeah I checked and it's a double

Comment: May you insert a breakpoint on  *e.Value = String.Format(""0.00", e.Value)* to be sure that you execute the instruction. It should work.

Comment: @Graffito yeah, the value just comes up as 0.00 when a row is added

Comment: @Graffito And there is an error due to there being two "" infront of 0.00, so I just made it String.Format("0.00", e.Value) - was that a typo or intentional?

Comment: It was a typo :(. sorry.

Comment: Set the CellFormatting event via the designer or immediately after creation of the datagridview (before being binded to a datasource).

Comment: @GrantWinney Hey, I found the problem. I was inserting the data as a string when I converted the database value in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I was inserting a string into the column which was converted from a double to string when I was getting the value from the mySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You set the format to whatever the culture setting for currency is, like this:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

Comment: When do you set this? Poking around it seems like it is something you do after you load your data, according to last comment in this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9869adfa-dcda-4c27-aa3b-c5a88aebd360/datagridview-column-currency-format?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: I put it in the Cell formating event  `private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)` 
I tried putting it in after the data was added, but it still comes out as #.##00

Comment: Did you set any CultureInfo in the config file? You can also set that explicitly dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU");

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal price = 234284.999234m;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Value = price.ToString("#,##0.00");
```

Comment: I would include an explanation as to where the code needs to be entered and an explanation of why this code works.